# SyntaxError: invalid syntax _ Is it a version issue?

Tags: python

```
        if not os.path.exists(txt_fn):
            print 'text file {} does not exists'.format(txt_fn)
            continue
```

Error:

```
 print 'text file {} does not exists'.format(txt_fn)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am currently running python 2.7, so most likely issue i can think of is inconsistency with the version as the syntax might be in python 3.0 not supported but couldn't find a proof or fix it.

Comment: I think you are using Python 3 to execute the Python 2.x code.

Comment: Any adjustment you can think of to properly migrate that code section.

Comment: Call print like a function  -- `print(...)`

Comment: python2: print 'x', python3: print('x')

Comment: Tested on 2.7. No errors in the code.